# ffmpeg + (large) metadata text = Segmentation Fault

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, segmentation-fault

I’m attempting to insert a large amount of text data into an mp4 using `-metadata title='"+JSON.stringify(filedata)+"'`. This works fine for small amounts metadata text but not for large ones. With large metadata text, averaging 2 MB, I get `Segmentation Fault`. I have tried adding `-moov_size 4500000` but this does not work. Is there something else I can try?

Here’s the full code. Again, it works for small files.

```
exec("ffmpeg -y -i /var/www/html/video/"+temp+" -metadata title='"+JSON.stringify(filedata)+"' -f mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -moov_size 4500000  -movflags +faststart "+file, {cwd: '/var/www/html/video/'})**
```

Comment: a) you mean the size of the file, not the metadata string, right? b) remove `moov_size` - it will lead to failure for files with lots of frames.

Comment: @gyan
a) no, the metadata string. When this text data is large, the muxing fails.